# User Control access from code behind problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control called adminMenu and I use it in my index.aspx and all is fine, but I need to access a MenuItem in adminMenu and need to change NavigateUrl on the MenuItem.  Tried this code with no luck:

```
MenuItem MaintenanceReports = this.adminMenu.FindItem("MaintenanceReports");
```

Not sure if I should be accessing adminMenu properties from controls code behind, but when I try from controls code behind was not able to access it either, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of this adminMenu? Second thing, why do you want to change NavigateUrl from your code? I smell some realy bad thing here, if you want to change navigateUrl (which comes from where?) only in one specific menu item with hardcoded name.

Comment: I'm going to go with the assumption that your controls within the UserControl are all declared as private members. You could a) make them public, or b) expose a method/property to access them.

Comment: Type is System.Web.UI.Control, need to change begginning of url to point to correct SSRS server. There is nothing in Code behind of Control named AdminMenu.ascx, just contains Menu with MenuItems. I think this url change should take place in AdminMenu.ascx vode behind but I have no luck accessing Menu with ID="adminMenu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was MenuItem I was searching for was actually a Sub-MenuItem an I needed to include path.

```
MenuItem MaintenanceReports = this.adminMenu.FindItem("Reports/MaintenanceReports");
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a property in the adminMenu user control that return the Menu such as the code below

```
public Button MyButton
{
    get { return this.btnTest; }
}
```

From the page you can write

```
this.adminMenu.MyButton.Text = "test";
```